# bashrc file has correct file paths but conda command not found for anaconda

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, anaconda, conda

I removed and reinstalled `anaconda3` in a different directory. After installing I updated my `$PATH` and `bashrc` files to the correct directory which is `/media/bcr/HDD/anaconda3`. However when calling `conda` from the command terminal I get the dreaded `conda: command not found`.

I tried the solutions offered for similar questions and none worked for except `source /media/bcr/HDD/anaconda3/bin` which opens `$(root)` in the terminal and then recognizes all the `conda` commands. I know this works but is massively inconvenient and am wondering why it would be required to do this every time when I did not have to do it previously when `anaconda` was installed in my `Home` directory.

When I run `echo $PATH` this is the result:

`/media/bcr/HDD/anaconda3/bin:/media/bcr/HDD/anaconda3:/home/bcr/bin:/home/bcr/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin:/snap/bin:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin:/home/bcr/bin:/home/bcr/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin:/snap/bin`

Here's my current `.bashrc` file:

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi

export PATH="/media/bcr/HDD/anaconda3:$PATH:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/media/bcr/HDD/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda-8.0
```

Comment: Can you make sure you have conda in "/media/bcr/HDD/anaconda3/bin" and it has execute permission(ls -al will show that)?

Comment: I think so see: `drwxrwxrwx 1 bcr bcr  65536 Dec 12 09:29 bin`

Comment: Do "ls -al /media/bcr/HDD/anaconda3/bin/conda"

Comment: Sorry I reread your question here it is `-rwxrwxrwx 1 bcr bcr      231 Dec 12 09:28 conda`

Comment: Why don't you simply put `source /media/bcr/HDD/anaconda3/bin` (if indeed that really works? It looks like you are lacking something after `bin` since it sounds like a directory name, and is listed as one in your `PATH`) in your `.bashrc` or similar?  What other conda-related stuff do you have in your shell's startup files?

Comment: @tripleee I'm not sure what you mean. I've added my `.bashrc` file if that will help. If you have a suggestion please answer the question with your solution so I can test it. Thank you.

Comment: If I knew what to fix I would not be asking for more information, would I? The 231-byte `conda` file is probably a fairly simple script; does it contain anything interesting? It's in your `PATH` so I don't understand where the "file not found" is coming from, but if it mucks up things and then tries to call the "real" `conda` from a location which no longer exists, then maybe...?